# SQL Server / Classic ASP: can I apply row lock on a row in a select statement so it cannot be grabbed simultaneously by two users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am using classic ASP and SQL Server 2005 on IIS7. I have a process that issues serialized product items to customers one after the other. When we get really busy, I am seeing occasions where two users are pulling the same row, for example, ID5, a second or two apart.

It appears that the User 2 selects the same row that User 1 selected a second or two before, then User 2 is assigned the record ID5 also, before my update can assign it to exclusively to User 1, and thus, force user 2 to take the next record.

I may have 10 items in `MyTable`, 4 are sold, 6 are available. So the next record available would be ID5

Basically, my select code is two part:

PART1:

```
Select top 1 * 
from MyTable 
where ProdNumber = 'ProdNum' and Sold = 0  order by id
```

then, if exists:

PART2:

```
update MyTable 
set Sold = 1 
where id = 'record selected above'
```

User 1 will grab the record ID5, then before PART2 can execute, User 2 grabs the same record ID5. The result is that User1's Part2 is literally overwritten as the buyer on the record ID5 by User 2.

Ive read and read this forum and others about locking but have not seen anything that seems to apply directly to my situation and code method. Does anyone have any advice for me. Other than quitting SQL Server and Classic ASP? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using transactions therefore you should check the sold status prior to the update and inform the user or raise and exception is the record has been modified prior to the read.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id='record selected above' AND Sold=0)
update MyTable set Sold = 1 where id = 'record selected above'
ELSE 
RAISERROR(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but if there is a UPDLOCK from the initial select above, how could it have sold since selecting it? I thought the whole idea of the UPDLOCK was to lock the selected record until I can get it updated> please elaborate... And thank you so much for your help and input.

Comment: You should put the connection in a transaction state or at least use a store procedure that handles this prior to your commit.

Answer (score 0):

The way SQL Server normally works is to put a *shared lock* on a row that's being read, and asking for an *exclusive lock* on a row that's being updated. Shared locks are compatible with another shared lock - so two users can read the same row at the same time.

What you could do is signal to SQL Server that you're not just selecting for display - but that you're really intending to update that row you're reading later on. In that case, an update lock is put on the row when it's read, and that update lock is incompatible with a second update lock on the same row - so basically preventing the second user from reading that row when user 1 has already read it.

So you basically need to put your "read then update" steps into a transaction, and use a table hint on your `SELECT`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM MyTable WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE ProdNumber = 'ProdNum' AND Sold = 0  
ORDER BY id

UPDATE MyTable 
SET Sold = 1 
WHERE id = 'record selected above'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

See the [relevant MSDN documentation on table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) and read the section on `UPDLOCK` for more background info.

Comment: Thank You for the advice. I have implemented and now I will wait & c. I do have one question. Does it matter that my select statement & update immediately following are configured differently from your example? Using clascASP as I am, my code uses a different syntax and structure such as in my initial query. Rather than you example, I am creating a server object and & ActiveConnection using an execute command at the end.  In other words, do I have to also structure my select statement & update as you have with the Begin Transaction and Commit Transaction, or will my ".Execute" be sufficient?